Document an inherited property dinamically created from parent class in JSDoc?
I'm extending a Controller class which (dynamically) adds a property named clearResultValue:
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {}

I want to document clearResultValue so I can get a basic check of this.clearResultValue in my IDE.
Seems an easy task but it seems not working, at least without redefining the property itself:
/**
 * @property {boolean} clearResultValue
 */
export default class extends Controller {
}

Neither:
export default class extends Controller {
  /**
   * @property {boolean} clearResultValue
   */
}


Why not simple predefine it since its going to be there anyway? ... { /** @type {boolean} */ clearResultValue; } ? Otherwise you could perhaps @extends {{clearResultValue: boolean}}?

Hey @somethinghere thanks, what do you mean with "predefine it"?

Already add it to your class but leave it empty. I guess I meant "initialise". Basically class A extends B { clearResultValue; } will be read by typescript as having a property named clearResultValue. If your class has it anyway, just initialise it. Maybe even already initialise it with a relevant value, clearResultValue = false or something and JSDoc will pick up the type and property anyway?

@somethinghere there are a lot of dynamic properties added by the parent class, the solution of adding each dynamic property will clutter my class, I'd like to avoid that...

Dynamic properties don't document well regardless. If  you don’t like documenting, this was moot to begin with. You will have to define it somewhere. Might as well do it where it’s expected, dynamic or not.
